# Disabling links using Javascript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I currently have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.usuarios-online.com/usuarios.php?v=www.bitchimblonde.tumblr.com"></script> <a href="http://www.usuarios-online.com/en/">mermaids in paradise. </a>
```

I know little to nothing about Java and coding, but want to disable the click through link to the stats page. 'http://www.usuarios-online.com/usuarios.php?'

Can anybody help me at all? I've heard about javascript:void(0) but have no idea how to implement it into my code.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java??

Comment: Is there a page this is working on? I can't really tell what the external js is doing to your poor dom without seeing it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you're right bad tag. Kevin, java is an entirely different language that has nothing to do with this other than they both follow ECMA script standards.

Comment: @FlavorScape, here's the link to the site: http://summers-in-cali.tumblr.com/

Comment: @KevinSkittlesNan Java and JavaScript are two different languages, they just have similar names.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `a` node by the text node in the `a` element:

```
myANode.parentNode.replaceChild(myANode.firstChild, myANode);
```

This makes the `a` element to an ordinary text node.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Useless Link</a>
```

Comment: Doesn't work as the script fetches data from: http://www.usuarios-online.com/usuarios.php?v=www.bitchimblonde.tumblr.com. I don't know how to implement <a href= into this.

Comment: Also, do you konw anything about 'return false'?

Comment: I want this link: http://www.usuarios-online.com/usuarios.php?v=www.bitchimblonde.tumblr.com to be 'unclickable'. However, the script fetches data from the link (how many users online). Is it possible to disable click-through?

Comment: Okay. So how/where do I put javascript:void(0) into this code?
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.usuarios-online.com/usuarios.php?v=www.bitchimblonde.tumblr.com"></script> <a href="http://www.usuarios-online.com/en/">mermaids in paradise. </a>

Comment: You only have 1 link in that code, the other one just includes a javascript file in your html code. So to make that disabled, where it says <a href="usuarios-online.com/en/">mermaids in paradise.</a> change that to <a href="javascript:void(0);">mermaids in paradise.</a>

Comment: This disables mermaids in paradise. But maybe the link to the site would help. http://summers-in-cali.tumblr.com/

The number before 'mermaids in paradise' still links to a page. Is there any way to disable this?

Answer (score 0):

With [jquery](http://jquery.com/):

```
// this prevents the code to execute before the DOM Tree is ready
$(document).ready(function(){

    // when clicking #mylink, execute this function
    $('#mylink').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

With `#mylink` being the element's id attribute. You can download jquery [here](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js) and call it with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

assuming you named your jquery file: `jquery.js` and put it in a folder named `js`.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the href property to a value you are happy with, e.g.

```
aLink.href = '';
```

To do every link in the document:

```
var links = document.links;
for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  links[i].href = '';
}
```